# Access an element in an object with a dynamic name

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I access a element if the name is based on a concatenated value of a string and a number ? I am using twilio and they don't store images not in an array but return a flat file which returns a new element name for each which looks like MediaUrl0, MediaUrl1, MediaUrl2 and so on. Also there is a NumMedia field which would be for 3 attachments 3.

so I use the following

```
if ( message.NumMedia > 0) {
    let i
    for (i=0; i < message.NumMedia; i++) {
        console.log(`message.MediaUrl${i}`)
    }
}
```

but that does not provide me the actual value but a string of `MediaUrl0` since it is not an array I can't use `message.MediaUrl[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Jeremy said. Originally you were creating a template string by having the back-tick come before the object that contained the property you were attempting to access. You can't use dot notation `obj.prop` when accessing properties dynamically.

```js
for (i=0; i < message.NumMedia; i++) {
  console.log(message[`MediaUrl${i}`])
}}
```